# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure asp .net core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[image: This is the error I'm getting]I'm having problems visit my site on a browser and this is the error I'm getting (see pic). I'm able to open the project in cli with dotnet project.dll command, what I want is to open it in a browser (like: server.com\project). I published the project in a folder and I also chose self-contained deployment mode. I couldn't find a right solution to questions that were asked. I'm using .net core 5.

Comment: How did you deploy, why did you visit `server.com\project`, did you use a virtual application?

Comment: This is common error, just follow this tutorial, https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/how-to-fix-error-502-5-process-failure-asp-net-core/, it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for this is that you haven't installed the .NET Core runtime on the server.

Check the download page from here [Download .NET 5.0 Runtime and SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0)

Comment: This was the right answer for me!